# hiearchical data, catel, and MVVM

Tags: wpf, linq, data-binding, mvvm, catel

I'm working with Catel, MVVM, WPF and am wondering about how to work with nested/hiearchical data.

Let's say from a database I've got a list of Customers, each with a list of Invoices, each with a list of InvoiceItems.  Customers own many Invoices which own many InvoiceItems.

I've got a working solution, but I do not like it. My approach was to build a collection of classes that would act a kind of like an ado.net “dataset.” A class would represent each layer of the hiearchy.

This top level class, CustomerModel, would contain a collection of of InvoiceBlocks:

**CustomerModel**
ObservableCollection of < InvoicesBlocks >

Each InvoceBlock would contain an Invoice and a collection of InvoiceItems:

**InvoiceBlock**
   Invoice
ObservableCollection of < InvoiceItems >

It seemed clever until wading through the databinding path= satements. There are also times when I have to loop through the sets mamaully to update totals, defeating a major selling point of MVVM.

So, I've decided to learn more about grouping with LINQ queries and databinding. Is this the way the pros do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make each view model responsible for using the right services to retrieve the data.

***Note that I did not use Catel properties to make it easy to understand, but you can simply use [Catel.Fody](http://www.catelproject.com/tools/catel-fody/) or rewrite the properties to get Catel properties.***

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    private readonly IInvoiceService _invoiceService;

    public CustomerViewModel(ICustomer customer, IInvoiceService invoiceService)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => customer);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => invoiceService);

        Customer = customer;
        _invoiceService = invoiceService;
    }

    public ICustomer Customer { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<IInvoice> Invoices { get; private set; }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        var customerInvoices = _invoiceService.GetInvoicesForCustomer(Customer.Id);
        Invoices = new ObservableCollection<IInvoice>(customerInvoices);
    }
}


public class InvoiceViewModel
{
    private readonly IInvoiceService _invoiceService;

    public InvoiceViewModel(IIinvoice invoice, IInvoiceService invoiceService)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => invoice);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => invoiceService);

        Invoice = invoice;
        _invoiceService = invoiceService;
    }

    public IInvoice Invoice { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<IInvoiceBlock> InvoiceBlocks { get; private set; }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        var invoiceBlocks = _invoiceService.GetInvoiceBlocksForInvoice(Invoice.Id);
        InvoiceBlocks = new ObservableCollection<IInvoiceBlock>(invoiceBlocks);
    }
}
```

Now you are fully in control what happens when.

Comment: I'm using ADO.NET Entity Model: using(var = new DataEntity()) Should I try to create a service for that, or call it directly from, say an InvoiceService? Thank you.

Comment: Got it! I put the ADO.NET Entity Model, DataEntities(), in it's own service. Sweet.